# Allocation of bytes for local variables of a function and Is the POP instruction called only once

Tags: c, unix, assembly, x86

I'm trying to understand the assembly code during a recursive function call.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int recursive(int no){
  if(no > 1){
    no--;
    recursive(no);
    printf("\n %d \n",no);
  }
  else if(no == 1){
    return 1;
  }
}

int main(){
  int a = 10;
  recursive(a);
  return 0;
}
```

disassembly :

```
   .file   "sample2.c"
        .section        .rodata
.LC0:
        .string "\n %d \n"
        .text
.globl recursive
        .type   recursive, @function
recursive:
        pushl   %ebp
        movl    %esp, %ebp
        subl    $24, %esp
        cmpl    $1, 8(%ebp)
        jle     .L2
        subl    $1, 8(%ebp)
        movl    8(%ebp), %eax
        movl    %eax, (%esp)
        call    recursive
        movl    $.LC0, %eax
        movl    8(%ebp), %edx
        movl    %edx, 4(%esp)
        movl    %eax, (%esp)
        call    printf
        jmp     .L5
.L2:
        cmpl    $1, 8(%ebp)
        jne     .L5
        movl    $1, %eax
        movl    %eax, %edx
        movl    %edx, %eax
        jmp     .L4
.L5:
.L4:
        leave
        ret
        .size   recursive, .-recursive
.globl main
        .type   main, @function
main:
        pushl   %ebp
        movl    %esp, %ebp
        andl    $-16, %esp
        subl    $32, %esp
        movl    $10, 28(%esp)
        movl    28(%esp), %eax
        movl    %eax, (%esp)
        call    recursive
        movl    $0, %eax
        leave
        ret
        .size   main, .-main
        .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5) 4.4.5"
        .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

I could understand .LC0 always holds the string literals. But I dont know what it really means. Would like to understand the code during the function call recursion was made.
I could not understand what this piece of assembly code does,

```
        subl    $24, %esp
        cmpl    $1, 8(%ebp)
        jle     .L2
        subl    $1, 8(%ebp)
        movl    8(%ebp), %eax
        movl    %eax, (%esp)
        call    recursive
        movl    $.LC0, %eax
        movl    8(%ebp), %edx
        movl    %edx, 4(%esp)
        movl    %eax, (%esp)
        call    printf
        jmp     .L5
.L2:
        cmpl    $1, 8(%ebp)
        jne     .L5
        movl    $1, %eax
        movl    %eax, %edx
        movl    %edx, %eax
        jmp     .L4
```

Q1:
The recursive function contains 1 parameter. so after the padding alignment, it has to be 8. why is it 24.

Also in .L2 ,

```
        movl    $1, %eax
        movl    %eax, %edx
        movl    %edx, %eax
        jmp     .L4
```

Q2:
we have moved '1' to the accumulater, why are we moving again to data register and then back to the accumulator.

Q3:
Are we popping out of stack. If leave is used for popping out of stack, are we not popping the rest of the 8 stack frames ?

Comment: You have a whole bunch of essentially unrelated questions about x86 assembler.  Could you please edit your question to focus on **one** issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the only thing in your post that matches your title:

> Why are we not popping out from the stack and only push instruction in the assembly.

Because `leave` is equivalent to:

```
movl %ebp, %esp
popl %ebp
```